# How to make both the top and side navigation bar fixed? HTML-CSS

Tags: html, css

Hello it is my first time learning html-css and I want to make a traditional website that have both the top bar for searches and login and the side bar for navigation. I found a youtube video that helps me deal with the side bar and it it fixed. But the top navigation bar is not fixed and will be left behind if the user will scroll down

Normal Website:
[image]

Website Scrolled down:
[image]

Website using the "position: fixed;" in the menu class
[image]

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>SYPHYM</title>
</head>
<style>

body
{
    background: white;
    margin: 0;
}
.menu
{
    width: 100%;
    background: #4b4276;
    overflow: auto;

}

.menu ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 60px;
}
.menu li
{
    float: left;
    
}
.menu ul li a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 130px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}
.menu li a:hover
{
    opacity: 0.5;
    font-size:19px;

}
.search-form
{
    margin-top: 15px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 100px

}
input[type=text]
{
    width: 300px;
    padding: 7px;
    border: none;
}
button
{
    
    float: right;
    background: orange;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 7px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    border: none;
}
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}

body{
   background-color: #f3f5f9;
}

.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper .sidebar{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #4b4254;
  padding: 30px 0px;
  position: fixed;
}

.wrapper .sidebar h2{
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li{
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bdb8d7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.05);
}    

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a{
  color: #bdb8d7;
  display: block;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a .fas{
  width: 25px;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li:hover{
  background-color: #594f8d;
}
    
.wrapper .sidebar ul li:hover a{
  color: #fff;
}

.wrapper .main_content{
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.wrapper .main_content .header{
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #717171;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e4e8;
}

.wrapper .main_content .info{
  margin: 20px;
  color: #717171;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.wrapper .main_content .info div{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

@media (max-height: 500px){
  .social_media{
    display: none !important;
  }
}
</style>
<body>
<nav class = "menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href = "#"> <b>SYPHYM</a> </li>
        <li><a href = "#"> Join </li>
        <li><a href = "#"> Sign In</a> </li>
    </ul>
<form class = "search-form">
    <input type = "text" placeholder = "Search">
    <button> Search </button>
</form>
</nav>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <h2>User</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"></i>My Orders</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"></i>My Commisions</a></li>
        </ul> 
        <br>
        <h2>Categories</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"></i>Music</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"></i>Art</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"></i>Writing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"></i>Video</a></li>
        </ul> 
    </div>
    <div class="main_content">
        <div class="header">Welcome!! Have a nice day.</div>  
        <div class="info">
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro, praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos perferendis eos? Consequuntur!</div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro, praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos perferendis eos? Consequuntur!</div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro, praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos perferendis eos? Consequuntur!</div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro, praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos perferendis eos? Consequuntur!</div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro, praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos perferendis eos? Consequuntur!</div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro, praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos perferendis eos? Consequuntur!</div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro, praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos perferendis eos? Consequuntur!</div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro, praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos perferendis eos? Consequuntur!</div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro, praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos perferendis eos? Consequuntur!</div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Sorry for the question I am totally stumped I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `position: fixed` and set the correct `z-index` in menu fixed the issue:

```css
  body {
      background: white;
      margin: 0;
    }
    .menu {
      width: calc(100% - 200px);
      background: #4b4276;
      overflow: auto;
      position: fixed;
      right: 0;
      z-index: 200;
    }

    .menu ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
      line-height: 60px;
    }
    .menu li {
      float: left;
    }
    .menu ul li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      width: 130px;
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    }
    .menu li a:hover {
      opacity: 0.5;
      font-size: 19px;
    }
    .search-form {
      margin-top: 15px;
      float: right;
      margin-right: 100px;
    }
    input[type='text'] {
      width: 300px;
      padding: 7px;
      border: none;
    }
    button {
      float: right;
      background: orange;
      color: white;
      border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
      cursor: pointer;
      position: absolute;
      padding: 7px;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      border: none;
    }
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      list-style: none;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    }

    body {
      background-color: #f3f5f9;
    }

    .wrapper {
      display: flex;
      position: relative;
    }

    .wrapper .sidebar {
      width: 200px;
      height: 100%;
      background: #4b4254;
      padding: 30px 0px;
      position: fixed;
    }

    .wrapper .sidebar h2 {
      color: #fff;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      text-align: center;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
    }

    .wrapper .sidebar ul li {
      padding: 15px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #bdb8d7;
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
      border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
    }

    .wrapper .sidebar ul li a {
      color: #bdb8d7;
      display: block;
    }

    .wrapper .sidebar ul li a .fas {
      width: 25px;
    }

    .wrapper .sidebar ul li:hover {
      background-color: #594f8d;
    }

    .wrapper .sidebar ul li:hover a {
      color: #fff;
    }

    .wrapper .main_content {
      width: 100%;
      margin-left: 200px;
    }

    .wrapper .main_content .header {
      padding: 20px;
      background: #fff;
      color: #717171;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e4e8;
    }

    .wrapper .main_content .info {
      margin: 20px;
      color: #717171;
      line-height: 25px;
    }

    .wrapper .main_content .info div {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    @media (max-height: 500px) {
      .social_media {
        display: none !important;
      }
    }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>SYPHYM</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"> SYPHYM</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Join</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Sign In</a></li>
      </ul>
      <form class="search-form">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search" />
        <button>Search</button>
      </form>
    </nav>

    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="sidebar">
        <h2>User</h2>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">My Orders</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">My Commisions</a></li>
        </ul>
        <br />
        <h2>Categories</h2>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Art</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Writing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Video</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="main_content">
        <div class="header">Welcome!! Have a nice day.</div>
        <div class="info">
          <div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed
            nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam
            blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet
            voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio
            perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam
            tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni
            tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro,
            praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum
            veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non
            obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa
            magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos
            perferendis eos? Consequuntur!
          </div>
          <div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed
            nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam
            blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet
            voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio
            perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam
            tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni
            tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro,
            praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum
            veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non
            obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa
            magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos
            perferendis eos? Consequuntur!
          </div>
          <div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed
            nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam
            blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet
            voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio
            perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam
            tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni
            tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro,
            praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum
            veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non
            obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa
            magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos
            perferendis eos? Consequuntur!
          </div>
          <div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed
            nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam
            blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet
            voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio
            perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam
            tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni
            tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro,
            praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum
            veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non
            obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa
            magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos
            perferendis eos? Consequuntur!
          </div>
          <div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed
            nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam
            blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet
            voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio
            perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam
            tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni
            tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro,
            praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum
            veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non
            obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa
            magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos
            perferendis eos? Consequuntur!
          </div>
          <div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed
            nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam
            blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet
            voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio
            perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam
            tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni
            tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro,
            praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum
            veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non
            obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa
            magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos
            perferendis eos? Consequuntur!
          </div>
          <div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed
            nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam
            blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet
            voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio
            perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam
            tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni
            tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro,
            praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum
            veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non
            obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa
            magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos
            perferendis eos? Consequuntur!
          </div>
          <div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed
            nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam
            blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet
            voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio
            perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam
            tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni
            tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro,
            praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum
            veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non
            obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa
            magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos
            perferendis eos? Consequuntur!
          </div>
          <div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed
            nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam
            blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet
            voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio
            perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam
            tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni
            tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro,
            praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum
            veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non
            obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa
            magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos
            perferendis eos? Consequuntur!
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
.menu {
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
    background: #4b4276;
    overflow: auto;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 200;
}
```

When using CSS `position: absolute | relative | fixed`, you need to make sure that the correct `z-index` value is used. The higher the value, the higher the stacking order for the HTML element. So in your case, without a `z-index` the text content is "above" the menu, and that's why the weird layout you showed in the above image.

Comment: You fix work but it eats the User and have a nice day

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I didn't notice that. Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

there is a new CSS position property **called sticky** that means the chosen element will be sticky with scroll, so you need to put all HTML elements for the header in  container div ..named with class header so your code will be :

```
.header {
position:sticky;
top:0;
left:0;
}
```

Comment: for more details check that video : 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9xygOHSuzQ8

Answer (score 1):

Was it necessary?

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>SYPHYM</title>
</head>
<style>

body
{
    background: white;
    margin: 0;
}
.menu
{
    width: 100%;
    background: #4b4276;
    overflow: auto;

}

.menu ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 60px;
}
.menu li
{
    float: left;
    
}
.menu ul li a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 130px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}
.menu li a:hover
{
    opacity: 0.5;
    font-size:19px;

}
.search-form
{
    margin-top: 15px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 100px

}
input[type=text]
{
    width: 300px;
    padding: 7px;
    border: none;
}
button
{
    
    float: right;
    background: orange;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 7px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    border: none;
}
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}

body{
   background-color: #f3f5f9;
}

.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper .sidebar{
  width: 300px;
  /*height: 100%;*/
  height: 100vh;
  background: #4b4254;
  padding: 30px 0px;
  /*position: fixed;*/
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.wrapper .sidebar h2{
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li{
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bdb8d7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.05);
}    

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a{
  color: #bdb8d7;
  display: block;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a .fas{
  width: 25px;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li:hover{
  background-color: #594f8d;
}
    
.wrapper .sidebar ul li:hover a{
  color: #fff;
}

.wrapper .main_content{
  width: 100%;
  /*margin-left: 200px;*/
}

.wrapper .main_content .header{
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #717171;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e4e8;
}

.wrapper .main_content .info{
  margin: 20px;
  color: #717171;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.wrapper .main_content .info div{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

@media (max-height: 500px){
  .social_media{
    display: none !important;
  }
}
</style>
<body>
<nav class = "menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href = "#"> <b>SYPHYM</a> </li>
        <li><a href = "#"> Join </li>
        <li><a href = "#"> Sign In</a> </li>
    </ul>
<form class = "search-form">
    <input type = "text" placeholder = "Search">
    <button> Search </button>
</form>
</nav>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <h2>User</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"></i>My Orders</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"></i>My Commisions</a></li>
        </ul> 
        <br>
        <h2>Categories</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"></i>Music</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"></i>Art</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"></i>Writing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"></i>Video</a></li>
        </ul> 
    </div>
    <div class="main_content">
        <div class="header">Welcome!! Have a nice day.</div>  
        <div class="info">
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro, praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos perferendis eos? Consequuntur!</div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro, praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos perferendis eos? Consequuntur!</div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro, praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos perferendis eos? Consequuntur!</div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro, praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos perferendis eos? Consequuntur!</div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro, praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos perferendis eos? Consequuntur!</div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro, praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos perferendis eos? Consequuntur!</div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro, praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos perferendis eos? Consequuntur!</div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro, praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos perferendis eos? Consequuntur!</div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed nobis ut exercitationem atque accusamus sit natus officiis totam blanditiis at eum nemo, nulla et quae eius culpa eveniet voluptatibus repellat illum tenetur, facilis porro. Quae fuga odio perferendis itaque alias sint, beatae non maiores magnam ad, veniam tenetur atque ea exercitationem earum eveniet totam ipsam magni tempora aliquid ullam possimus? Tempora nobis facere porro, praesentium magnam provident accusamus temporibus! Repellendus harum veritatis itaque molestias repudiandae ea corporis maiores non obcaecati libero, unde ipsum consequuntur aut consectetur culpa magni omnis vero odio suscipit vitae dolor quod dignissimos perferendis eos? Consequuntur!</div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```